# How I can give access for everyone around the world to my spring boot app that started on my computer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, ip

I started my spring boot app on my computer, and now I can easily make Http requests to `http://localhost:8080/`. How I can give access to everyone around the world to make Http requests to my app without deploying this app anywhere?

Comment: Sometimes you can get this working by adding port forwarding in your router settings.

Comment: Are you looking for something like SoapUI?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about configuring home networks belong on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker no, the OP is trying to set up a server of his own, providing his spring-boot app to the outside world

Comment: Please see this link : How to convert your laptop/desktop into a server and host internet accessible website on it (https://afteracademy.com/blog/how-to-convert-your-laptop-desktop-into-a-server-and-host-internet-accessible-website-on-it-part-1-545940164ab9)

Comment: You can use Ngrok.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deploy it in any cloud services, At-least you need to have a **public IP**. Without public IP, other user can access your server.

After getting access of public IP you need to set it in your PC. After that run the spring boot app, with public IP configured. Or you can set public IP in a router or gateway and **redirect/forward** port to your locally running application PORT.